# DataFrame loc cannot find elements that do exist in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` that is a client list from a brand. It contains the client id, client name, payment date and amount paid, like the example below. The client id is an 11 character number, with a few of them starting with 0:

`df`

| Payment date | client_id | Client name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-07-16 | 24145014193 | Jim Horne | 45.000000 |
| 2019-07-17 | 26163816280 | Tom Newman | 58.000000 |
| 2019-07-18 | 08789784317 | Jason Richard | 71.000000 |
| 2020-07-20 | 24145014193 | Jim Horne | 75.000000 |
| 2019-07-24 | 08789784317 | Jason Richard | 44.000000 |
| 2019-07-27 | 02515511520 | Dan Smith | 24.000000 |
| 2019-08-03 | 26163816280 | Tom Newman | 56.000000 |

Using `dtypes` I see that the column client_id is labeled as `object`, just like Client Name.

However, when I use `loc` to select just a row with a specified `client_id`, it manages to find some but not all of them:

`test_tom = df.loc[df['client_id'] == 26163816280]`
`test_tom`

| Payment date | client_id | Client name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-07-17 | 26163816280 | Tom Newman | 58.000000 |
| 2019-08-03 | 26163816280 | Tom Newman | 56.000000 |

`test_jim = df.loc[df['client_id'] == 24145014193]`
`test_jim`

| Payment date | client_id | Client name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I tried using `astype(float)` to convert string to float but it only resulted in error:

`df_brand_2['client_id'] = df_brand_2['client_id'].astype(float) could not convert string to float: '325.438.943-14'`

Weirdly, it appears with these . between the numbers even though the original df nor the original excel file had them.

What is happening? Why the code only manages to find one value but not the other? And what can I do to correct this?

Comment: The example dataframe in your question should include the rows that are causing your error.

Comment: In any case, the leading zeros are causing your client ID column to be read as generic objects. My guess it's that your errant value actually is in your raw data, you just haven’t found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

since client_id is a pandas object you should add the quotes in your condition :

```
test_jim = df.loc[df['client_id'] == '24145014193']
```

Comment: This might not work. It seems like pandas is reading some values as numbers and others as strings.

Comment: Paul, that's exactly what happened. Adding quotes was helpful and made 'test_jim' show the required rows, but if I do the same thing to 'test_tom', the rows disappear. And the opposite is also true: no quotes works on 'test_tom' but not on 'test_jim' . The conclusion I get is what you said: some values are being read as numbers and others as strings. Is there a way to normalize all the values?